# resizing uitableview on orientation change does not resize correctly

Tags: uitableview, orientation, screen-orientation, autoresize

I cannot resize the uitableview properly when changing the orientation of the screen. I can make one orientation work fine but not both.
I've tried 2 different methods: 1) using the autoresizingMask on the tableview and 2) using the layoutSubviews method and here are the results of each:

1) using the autoresizing almost works if I use

```
self.myTableView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

It shows correctly when in portrait and then I move to landscape it also shows correctly but not all the way to the end of the screen. In landscape I see a space on the left side and on the right side.
So, I thought let's just add the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth to the line of code above. It does make the uitableviewcell expand to the full screen in landscape but when I change the orientation it  does not maintain the same cell on the screen and sometimes it displays half of one cell and half of another cell in the middle of the screen.

2) Using auto layout. I get the same behavior as above when I use this code:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

  [super layoutSubviews];
    onLoadSize=self.contentView.bounds.size;
    self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, onLoadSize.width, onLoadSize.height);
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = self.myTableView.frame;
}
```

If I add an if statement testing for the orientation, then it works fine for that orientation in specific but not the other. If I test for both orientations I get the same behavior as described above.

Any help will be very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UITableViews usually occupy the full space of the parent view controller and typically don't need constraints or active resizing, unless you have more than one table view in a single view.

Consider managing the content of UITableViewCells (instead of managing the table view) by:
(1) Applying constraints to each custom cell in Interface Builder.
(2) Redrawing the cell's frame to fit the parent UItableView when the cell renders its subviews (layoutSubviews method).
(3) Calling [cell.contentView needsUpdateConstraints] to force the cell contents to redraw.

Here is some sample code for cell's custom class:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    resizeCell:self forView:[the cell's UITableViewController.view]
}
```

Here is a generic function you can add anywhere for reuse:

```
-(void)resizeCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forView:(UIView *)view
{
    cell.contentView.frame=CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x,
                                      cell.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                      view.frame.size.width,
                                      view.frame.size.width,
                                      cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Please note the cell's UITableViewController must be passed to the cell's custom class (as a member variable) for the code above to work.

Good luck!